# font size won't update automatically in markdown - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I have an issue with markdown in vs code.
When I want to change the font size of my text with ## such as ## text then I validate the markdown with the check, the text won't display in bigger font. I have to go back to the markdown, remove the space between ## and text and add it again for the font size to change in vs code.

Why is that and how to avoid doing this everytime?

Thank you!

I'm expecting that the font size changes automatically when I add ## with a space before the text

Comment: change in what? the markdown preview? The VS Code default markdown preview? or one from an extension?

Comment: The vs code default markdown preview

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.